# mongoDB Search without joins

Tags: node.js, mongodb, search, nosql, mean

I have two collections: Profiles and Employees.

Employees consists of firstName, lastName etc.

Profiles-Collection, amongst other data, has a bunch of key value pairs that describe the profession or level of experience, e.g.`"software-engineer": true, "javascript": 3`

Since you can't have joins in mongoDB I need to search each collection individually and then "join" that result. That leaves me with 2 options:

1) Have two separate search bars on the frontend so that I know which search query belongs to which collection

2) Have a single search bar and search both collections with the same query

Option two is implemented in a way that a search on a single collection either returns the desired data when the search query has a match or returns ALL data when the search query finds no match. That means searching after "John Doe" gives us john and searching after "angular" gives us all employees that work with angular. But it also means searching after "john angular" gives us all employees that work with angular OR are called john.

What I actually want is a AND search (like in option 1) but with a single search bar. Is there a way to implement this in MongoDB or is this only possible in a relational database?

Comment: You should read up on aggregation pipelines and $lookup - which might solve your problem another way.

Comment: Since $match has to be the first stage of the aggregation pipeline, I can only do a "join" with lookup after I already searched. I would need to search after the "join" though. So lookup won't be of much help here I think.